# Create ComboBox within a TitleAreaDialog (JFace dialog)

Tags: java, combobox, swt, jface

I am trying to create a combo box within a TitleAreaDialog of a JFace Dialog.
In the following code am I asking the user for the values for height and width and also the user has to choose the line strength out of the combo box (uneditable). This will be 1, 2, 3 or 4. This is what I have so far:

```
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class RectDialog extends TitleAreaDialog {

    private Text txtWidth;
    private Text txtHeight;
    private Text txtLineStrength;

    private String width;
    private String height;
    private String lineStrength;

    public RectDialog(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell);
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        super.create();
        setTitle("New Rectangle");
        // setMessage("", IMessageProvider.INFORMATION);
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite area = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        Composite container = new Composite(area, SWT.NONE);
        container.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
        container.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        container.setLayout(layout);

        createWidth(container);
        createHeight(container);
        createLineStrength(container);

        return area;
    }

    private void createLineStrength(Composite container) {
        // TODO: Create line strength
    }

    private void createHeight(Composite container) {
        Label lbtHeight = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
        lbtHeight.setText("Height");

        GridData dataHeight = new GridData();
        dataHeight.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        dataHeight.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;

        txtHeight = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER);
        txtHeight.setLayoutData(dataHeight);
    }

    private void createWidth(Composite container) {
        Label lbtWidth = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
        lbtWidth.setText("Height");

        GridData dataWidth = new GridData();
        dataWidth.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        dataWidth.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;

        txtWidth = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER);
        txtWidth.setLayoutData(dataWidth);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isResizable() {
        return true;
    }

    private void saveInput() {
        width = txtWidth.getText();
        height = txtHeight.getText();
//      lineStrength = txtLineStrength.getText();
    }

    @Override
    protected void okPressed() {
        saveInput();
        super.okPressed();
    }

    public String getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public String getLineStrength() {
        return lineStrength;
    }
}
```

I am now stuck at the method createLineStrength(). How can I input a combobox and then read the value in getLineStrength()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Combo lineHeight;

lineHeight = new Combo(parent, SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.BORDER);

lineHeight.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEAD, SWT.CENTER, false, false));

String [] choices = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};

lineHeight.setItems(choices);

lineHeight.select(0);  // Select "1" by default
```

`lineHeight.getSelectionIndex()` will return the current selection - so 0 for "1", 1 for "2"...