# Getting value of selected item in combo box eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

How do I get the value of the selected item from a combo box? I keep getting a null pointer exception when executing the saveInput method.

Here is my dialog code:

```
public class MyTitleAreaDialog extends TitleAreaDialog {

    private String age;    
    private Combo combo;    

    public MyTitleAreaDialog(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell);
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        super.create();
        setTitle("Age Box");
        setMessage("Please enter your info..", IMessageProvider.INFORMATION);
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {            
        Combo combo = new Combo(container, SWT.READ_ONLY);
        combo.setItems(new String[] {"21", "22", "23"});    
        return area;
    }

    private void saveInput() {        
        if(combo.getSelectionIndex() >= 0){
            age = combo.getItem(combo.getSelectionIndex());
        }        
    }

    @Override
    protected void okPressed() {
        saveInput();
        super.okPressed();
    }

    public String getSelectedAge() {
        return age;
    }        
}
```

Here is the handler code:

```
public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);

        MyTitleAreaDialog dialog = new MyTitleAreaDialog(window.getShell());

        dialog.create();
        if (dialog.open() == Window.OK) {           
            System.out.println(dialog.getSelectedAge());            
        }       
        return null;
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help..I'm new to Java and eclipse programming...thanks!!

Comment: Comprehensible question, with code supplied and issue explained! Recall: questions about errors/exceptions should be posted with full __error-message__ or (in this case) __stacktrace__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `createDialogArea` method is assigning the `Combo` to a **local** variable called `combo`, **not** the field called `combo`.

Replace:

```
Combo combo = new Combo(container, SWT.READ_ONLY);
```

with

```
combo = new Combo(container, SWT.READ_ONLY);
```

Comment: @txprogrammer for implementation of `createDialogArea` you may have a look at [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718599/create-combobox-within-a-titleareadialog-jface-dialog) equally well answered by _greg_.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that example, I didn't see it previously.